# How to know the default location of hadoop homepath

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have installed cloudera hadoop 2.0.0 CDH4 while doing i am not mentioning any

home path.It is working fine now. But when i ran JPS command.It was showing jps

process only.

So i tried to start the hadoop but I am unable to find the location of hadoop,

where It is actually stored. So can any one please help how to find the default

location.

Is there any commands are there to find the exact location of hadoop in my

system?

please help me on this issue.

Thanks,

Anbu k

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could try:

```
find / -name hadoop
```

Comment: Hi,
I have tried the above command. here which one i could use.
please reply.

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ find / -name hadoop;

Comment: usr/lib/hive/lib/php/packages/serde/org/apache/hadoop
/usr/lib/hive/docs/api/org/apache/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop-httpfs/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop-httpfs/webapps/webhdfs/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/hadoop/lib/service/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop
/usr/lib/mahout/lib/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/include/hadoop
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin/hadoop
/usr/bin/hadoop
/usr/share/doc/oozie-3.3.2+100/core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop

Comment: /usr/share/doc/oozie-3.3.2+100/core/apidocs/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop
/usr/share/doc/pig-0.11.0+42/api/org/apache/hadoop
/usr/share/doc/pig-0.11.0+42/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop
/usr/share/doc/whirr-0.8.2+15/apidocs/org/apache/whirr/service/hadoop
/usr/share/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop
/usr/share/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop
/usr/share/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/gen-py/hadoop
find: `/usr/lib64/audit': Permission denied
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ 

Thanks,
Anbu k.

Comment: I am not getting the exact location. Please help me on this problem.

Comment: Hadoop is a client program. You should not use it directly to start services. How did you install your CDH? If you have installed it with yum, you'll have your startup scripts located in /etc/init.d . If you have used Cloudera Manager to install, you'll have to use Cloudera Manager's web to start/stop your hadoop services.

Comment: I have not installed with yum.but i have started all services in Cloudera Manager --> All services --> Actions  --> I agree --> Its showing finished.And i checked the status for all the HDFS, Mapreduce as Good health.
Now also checked its showing only the jps service only.

How could i start now?

Thanks in Advance,
Anbu k

Comment: If you are using Cloudera Manager this is the only tool you can use to start/stop hadoop daemons. Probably you are not seeing your daemons with jps because there are several java distributions installed. Try running "find / -name jps | grep cloudera" and use the jps command that comes out.

Comment: Sorry its not working. If it possible can you help me through remotely?
Because once i start the hadoop by using start-all.sh, rest of the code will work fine. please
Thanks in advance,
Anbu